# PyCharm remote interpreter [Errno 2] No such file or directory: nvcc

Tags: path, pycharm, nvcc

I have set up a remote interpreter in PyCharm on a VM. Have set the correct interpreter with all libraries installed. 
However, when I execute the program (which includes a part in C) within PyCharm I get the following error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvcc': 'nvcc'`

However, when I execute the program on the VM through shell all works fine.

**I assume this has to do with some path mapping but I don't know how to fix it.**

When exec. in PyCharm I have the following on

`'PATH': ['/usr/local/bin', '/usr/bin', '/bin', '/usr/games']`

On VM I also have cuda in the path:

`'PATH': ['/usr/local/cuda/bin', '/home/<user>/anaconda3/envs/deep-drr/bin', '/usr/local/cuda/bin','/usr/local/bin', '/usr/bin', '/bin', '/usr/local/games', '/usr/games']`

How do I add that extra path to cuda to the PyCharm remote interpreter?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Solution was (as nvcc is clearly in the path on the remote machine):

1. `echo $PATH` on the remote and copy
2. had over to the *Run/Debug Configuration* for that interpreter
3. click the `$` next to *Environment Variables*
4. paste the content in a new or existing *PATH* variable